# PHP combine two multidimensional arrays and use one array as key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to combine two multidimensional arrays in a way that in the resulting array, array1 values serve as keys for array2.

These are two example arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
   array('data1'),
   array('data2'),
   array('data3')
);

$array2 = array(
   array('5','12','4'),
   array('8','2','17'),
   array('20','15','3')
);
```

The resulting array should look like this:

```
$array = array(
   'data1' => array('5','12','4'),
   'data2' => array('8','2','17'),
   'data3' => array('20','15','3')
);
```

How could I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$array = [];
$count = count($array1);
for($index = 0; $index < $count; $index++)
{
   $array[$array1[$index][0]] = $array2[$index];
}
```

This should do what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_combine to combine keys and values to an new array. You can check the **[live demo here](https://eval.in/794555)**.

```
array_combine(array_map(function($v){return $v[0];},$array1), $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_map()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp), which lets you use user defined function.

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    array('data1'),
    array('data2'),
    array('data3')
);

$array2 = array(
    array('5', '12', '4'),
    array('8', '2', '17'),
    array('20', '15', '3')
);

function mapArray($array1, $array2) {
    return [$array1[0] => $array2];
}

$new_arr = array_map("mapArray", $array1, $array2);
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be succinctly accomplished using just two native php functions.
The only step before calling `array_combine()` is to reduce the depth of your first array.  To extract the first value from each subarray, just call `array_column()` and specify that you want all of the `0`-keyed values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Hbt0c))

```
$array1 = [['data1'], ['data2'], ['data3']];
$array2 = [['5', '12', '4'], ['8', '2', '17'], ['20', '15', '3']];

var_export(
    array_combine(array_column($array1, 0), $array2)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'data1' => 
  array (
    0 => '5',
    1 => '12',
    2 => '4',
  ),
  'data2' => 
  array (
    0 => '8',
    1 => '2',
    2 => '17',
  ),
  'data3' => 
  array (
    0 => '20',
    1 => '15',
    2 => '3',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array1 = array(
array('data1'),
array('data2'),
array('data3')
);
$array2 = array(
array('5','12','4'),
array('8','2','17'),
array('20','15','3')
);
$main_array=array(count($array1));
foreach($array as $array_item){
$array_item=array(count($array2));
for($i=1;$i<count($array2);$i++){
array.push($array_item,$array2[$i]);
}
array.push($main_array,$array_item);
}
echo "<br>";
print_r($main_array);
echo "</br>";
```